# Django django-filters ipaddress mysql

Tags: django, filter, django-filters

filter for ip not working properly

model.py

```
class Network(models.Model):
start_ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='both', blank=True, null=True)
end_ip_address =  models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='both', blank=True, null=True)
```

filters.py

```
class NetworkFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
 
    f_by_address = django_filters.CharFilter(method='filter_by_address', label="BY ADDRESS")

    def filter_by_address(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(start_ip_address__lt=value, end_ip_address__gt=value)


    class Meta:
        model = Network
        fields = ['id', 'start_ip_address',]
```

filter by address result to

```
SELECT `network_network`.`id`, start_ip_address, `network_network`.`end_ip_address` FROM `network_network` WHERE (`network_network`.`end_ip_address` > 10.172.148.12 AND `network_network`.`start_ip_address` < 10.172.148.12) ORDER BY `network_network`.`id` ASC
```

my table doesn contains so much records, but even now I got into the troubles.

```
mysql> SELECT  start_ip_address, end_ip_address  from network_network where (end_ip_address > '10.172.148.12' AND start_ip_address < '10.172.148.12');
+------------------+----------------+
| start_ip_address | end_ip_address |
+------------------+----------------+
| 10.172.14.1      | 10.172.15.254  |
| 10.172.148.1     | 10.172.149.254 |
+------------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT start_ip_address, end_ip_address  FROM network_network WHERE (INET_ATON("10.172.148.12") BETWEEN INET_ATON(start_ip_address) AND INET_ATON(end_ip_address));
+------------------+----------------+
| start_ip_address | end_ip_address |
+------------------+----------------+
| 10.172.148.1     | 10.172.149.254 |
+------------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Not sure what to do in order to make this filter working accurate over django ORM. Can't use raw SQL as example is simplified.

update: so far I put this as workaround, not sure how to include extra into this logic.

```
    def filter_by_address(self, queryset, name, value):
    #return queryset.filter(start_ip_address__lt=value, end_ip_address__gt=value)
    id_recs = Network.objects.raw('SELECT id FROM network_network WHERE (INET_ATON(%s) BETWEEN\
                                INET_ATON(start_ip_address) AND INET_ATON(end_ip_address))'
                              ,[value]
                              )
    ids = [rec.id for rec in id_recs]
    return queryset.filter(id__in=ids)
```

update2:
finally got this , to avoid an extra query

```
return queryset.extra(where=["(INET_ATON(%s) BETWEEN INET_ATON(start_ip_address) AND INET_ATON(end_ip_address))"], params=[value])
```

if there is a better solution, please share.

Answer (score 1):

If is not working probably with you, you can use **extra filter** to apply row sql condition

Please read more about [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra)